# I need some help in getting my first open source project running

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I needed some help in getting my first open source project that I want to work on to run on my machine. I have a 2018 MacBook Pro 15” running Big Sur 11.1 (20C69). I am using VS Code as my IDE. I have forked and cloned the repository for my project.

I have followed the instructions on how to get the app to run here:

https://github.com/bancodobrasil/stop-analyzing-embed

Here are the instructions on how to contribute:

https://github.com/bancodobrasil/stop-analyzing-embed/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

This is the issue I have been assigned, and I am going to work on:

https://github.com/bancodobrasil/stop-analyzing-embed/issues/72

I have first run “npm install” and then “npm run dev”.

Here are the errors I get in terminal:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run chsh -s /bin/zsh.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
ShoaibKhansMBP:stop-analyzing-embed shoaibkhan$ cd app
ShoaibKhansMBP:app shoaibkhan$ npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: stop-analyzing-embed@0.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR! react@"^16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR! peer react@">=16.9.0" from @testing-library/react-hooks@3.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react-hooks
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-test-renderer@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-test-renderer
npm ERR! peer react-test-renderer@">=16.9.0" from @testing-library/react-hooks@3.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react-hooks
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/shoaibkhan/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/shoaibkhan/.npm/_logs/2021-01-26T14_56_13_324Z-debug.log
ShoaibKhansMBP:app shoaibkhan$ npm run dev

stop-analyzing-embed@0.2.0 dev
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8008 yarn start
sh: yarn: command not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/shoaibkhan/Documents/Treehouse/Open Source Projects/stop-analyzing-embed/app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8008 yarn start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/shoaibkhan/.npm/_logs/2021-01-26T14_56_33_589Z-debug.log
ShoaibKhansMBP:app shoaibkhan$
```

Can someone please help me to get this running.

Thanks,

Shoaib Kamal Khan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells us that [yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn) is not installed. Looking at the `dev` script inside the `package.json` we can see the actual command that is run:

```
"dev": "REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8008 yarn start",
```

The problem is that it's not listed as a (dev-) dependency in the `package.json` (you might want to create a PR for that), hence you don't get it installed when doing `npm i` .

To fix this and install yarn, you should run the following:
`npm i -D yarn` or install it globally using `npm i -g yarn`.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot eol I will look into this further and then I will update the post. I really appreciate the help, thanks again!

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left if the answer solves your issue, thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this, as I have still not solved this issue. I am working on the issue with someone from the project.